# Maximum Size of Tweet JSON object

Tags: json, twitter, tweets

What is the maximum size for a Twitter's Tweet JSON object?

This link from Twitter docs [Tweet Object -- Twitter Developers](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object.html) mentions which attributes it may have, but does not specify the lengths/ranges for many attributes, and this does not seem to appear on any of the sub-pages as well.

Comment: This is not documented (to my knowledge), but I believe the maximum would be somewhere between 6-8k (assuming for example, maximum size of text, quoted Tweet, with extended media entities, and, potentially, any enterprise enrichments). Is there a specific reason to ask the question?

Comment: I need the maximum size to optimize my processing and loading process. The choice of available processing tools and optimization methods depend on whether the tweet can reliably fit in a 64KB block

Comment: I believe that would work reliably, on average the JSON data would be around 2.5-6k. I'm not aware of a reason for Tweet object to reach anything like 64k unless there was a bug of some kind.